SPIDEV on raspberry pi for TI DAC8568 producing distorted signals
I’m working on a Raspberry Pi project where I’ve transitioned from using an I2C-based HiFi DAC HAT (PCM5122) to an SPI-based DAC (Boost 8568). My goal is to output analog signals from processed EEG data from a DAC, but I’m encountering significant differences in the output signal quality. The new SPI DAC output is distorted compared to the clean signal produced by the I2C DAC HAT, when I check the outputs with an oscilloscope.
Image of signal output from HiFi DAC
Image of signal output from BOOST DAC 8568
I have tried lowering both the sample rate of the signal and max speed to see if that helped the solution, however the issue is still there. I am starting to wonder if it has to do with the clock component of the boost DAC, or if other SPI parameters need to be altered to produce the same clear signal output as the previous DAC and i2C interface.
import spidev
import numpy as np
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from scipy.io import wavfile

# Define DAC channels and their corresponding addresses (assuming 8 channels)
CHANNELS = {
   'A': 0b0000,  # Channel A address
   'B': 0b0001,  # Channel B address
   'C': 0b0010,  # Channel C address
   'D': 0b0011,  # Channel D address
   'E': 0b0100,  # Channel E address
   'F': 0b0101,  # Channel F address
   'G': 0b0110,  # Channel G address
   'H': 0b0111,  # Channel H address
}

# LDAC GPIO pin (adjust as needed)
LDAC_PIN = 17

def initialize_ldac():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(LDAC_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(LDAC_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)  # Default to inactive state

def trigger_ldac():
    GPIO.output(LDAC_PIN, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.001)
    GPIO.output(LDAC_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)

CHANNEL_MAP = {
    "A": 0,
    "B": 1,
    "C": 2,
    "D": 3,
    "E": 4,
    "F": 5,
    "G": 6,
    "H": 7
}

def build_command(channel, data):
    if isinstance(channel, str):
        channel = CHANNEL_MAP[channel.upper()]  # Map channel to integer
    data = int(data) & 0xFFFF  # Ensure data is a 16-bit value
    command = 0b0011 << 4 | (channel & 0x0F)  # Generate command
    msb = (command << 4) | ((data >> 12) & 0x0F)  # Upper nibble of data
    lsb = (data >> 4) & 0xFF  # Middle 8 bits of data
    return [msb, lsb]

def send_to_dac(spi, channel, value):
    command = build_command(channel, value)
    spi.xfer2(command)

def update_channels_with_ldac(spi, channel_values):
    for channel, value in channel_values.items():
        send_to_dac(spi, channel, value)
    trigger_ldac()

def set_all_channels_to_zero(spi):
    channel_values = {channel: 0 for channel in CHANNELS}
    update_channels_with_ldac(spi, channel_values)

def load_wav_file(file_path, desired_duration_seconds):
    # Load WAV file and normalize the signal
    sample_rate, signal = wavfile.read(file_path)
    if signal.ndim > 1:  # Handle multi-channel audio (stereo)
        signal = signal[:, 0]  # Use only the first channel
    max_amplitude = np.max(np.abs(signal))
    normalized_signal = signal / max_amplitude

    # Determine how many samples fit within the desired duration
    num_samples = int(sample_rate * desired_duration_seconds)
    if len(normalized_signal) > num_samples:
        normalized_signal = normalized_signal[:num_samples]
    else:
        # Repeat the signal to fit the desired duration
        repeated_signal = np.tile(normalized_signal, int(np.ceil(num_samples / len(normalized_signal))))
        normalized_signal = repeated_signal[:num_samples]

    # Clip and convert to 16-bit integers
    normalized_signal = np.clip(normalized_signal * 32767, -32768, 32767).astype(int)
    return normalized_signal, sample_rate

def play_wav_file(spi, wav_file, target_channel, desired_duration_seconds):
    audio_data, sample_rate = load_wav_file(wav_file, desired_duration_seconds)
    num_samples = len(audio_data)
    sample_interval = 1 / sample_rate  # Time interval between samples

    start_time = time.time()  # Record the start time
    for i, value in enumerate(audio_data):
        # Send data to the DAC
        channel_values = {channel: 0 for channel in CHANNELS}
        channel_values[target_channel] = value
        update_channels_with_ldac(spi, channel_values)

        # Ensure proper timing
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        expected_time = (i + 1) * sample_interval
        if elapsed_time < expected_time:
            time.sleep(expected_time - elapsed_time)

        # Stop playback if exceeded the desired duration
        if elapsed_time >= desired_duration_seconds:
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spi = spidev.SpiDev()
    spi.open(0, 0)
    spi.max_speed_hz = 500000
    spi.mode = 0b00

    initialize_ldac()

    try:
        target_channel = input("Enter the target channel (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H): ").strip().upper()
        if target_channel not in CHANNELS:
            raise ValueError("Invalid channel.")
        
        wav_file = 'wav file dest here'
        desired_duration_seconds = 7

        play_wav_file(spi, wav_file, target_channel, desired_duration_seconds)

    finally:
        set_all_channels_to_zero(spi)
        spi.close()
        GPIO.cleanup()


Check that the spec of the DAC and the data frame that you are sending it is in agreement about signed integers vs unsigned ones with a bias offset. That can easily scramble a waveform. Test it with a simple sawtooth generator output and you should be able to see what exactly is going on. Real life signals are just too difficult to recognise when they get a bit scrambled.

The second image looks like SCLK pin of SPI rather than analogue output.

that thumbnail of a picture says 2 ms/div. the other thumbnail of a thumbnail of a picture is essentially indecipherable.
